# Flutter/Dart: Split string by first occurrence

Tags: dart, split

Is there a way to *split* a string by some *symbol* but only at *first occurrence*?

**Example**: `date: '2019:04:01'` should be split into `date` and `'2019:04:01'`
It could also look like this `date:'2019:04:01'` or this `date   :   '2019:04:01'` and should still be split into `date` and `'2019:04:01'`

```
string.split(':');
```

I tried using the `split()` method. But it doesn't have a limit attribute or something like that.

Comment: Use `RegExp` in `split`.

Comment: How does this work?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You were never going to be able to do all of that, including trimming whitespace, with the split command. You will have to do it yourself. Here's one way:

```
String s = "date   :   '2019:04:01'";
int idx = s.indexOf(":");
List parts = [s.substring(0,idx).trim(), s.substring(idx+1).trim()];
```

Answer (score 35):

You can split the string, skip the first item of the list created and re-join them to a string.

In your case it would be something like:

```
var str = "date: '2019:04:01'";
var parts = str.split(':');
var prefix = parts[0].trim();                 // prefix: "date"
var date = parts.sublist(1).join(':').trim(); // date: "'2019:04:01'"
```

The trim methods remove any unneccessary whitespaces around the first colon.

Comment: I also thought about that. I hoped that there would be a cleaner solution.

Comment: Cleaner than that? Put it into an extension function called `splitFirst()` and you'll get it as clean as it gets. :-)

Comment: I'm don't really know how truly work dart but I think that this solution is way more complex that it should be, it read the whole string and create multiple substring while it should only read until it encounter the pattern and create only 2 string. I think the best solution is the solution of @WaltPurvis

Answer (score 10):

Just use the [split](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/split.html) method on the string. It accepts a delimiter/separator/pattern to split the text by. It returns a list of values separated by the provided delimiter/separator/pattern.

Usage:

```
const str = 'date: 2019:04:01';
final values = string.split(': '); // Notice the whitespace after colon
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it's possible, that there is no whitespace after the first :

Comment: In that case you can simple check if the string contains a whitespace or not. If it contains then use my solution else use ``string.split(":'")``

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by python, I've wrote this utility function to support string `split` with an optionally maximum number of splits. Usage:

```
split("a=b=c", "="); // ["a", "b", "c"]
split("a=b=c", "=", max: 1); // ["a", "b=c"]
split("",""); // [""] (edge case where separator is empty)
split("a=", "="); // ["a", ""]
split("=", "="); // ["", ""]
split("date: '2019:04:01'", ":", max: 1) // ["date", " '2019:04:01'"] (as asked in question)
```

Define this function in your code:

```
List<String> split(String string, String separator, {int max = 0}) {
  var result = List<String>();

  if (separator.isEmpty) {
    result.add(string);
    return result;
  }

  while (true) {
    var index = string.indexOf(separator, 0);
    if (index == -1 || (max > 0 && result.length >= max)) {
      result.add(string);
      break;
    }

    result.add(string.substring(0, index));
    string = string.substring(index + separator.length);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Online demo: https://dartpad.dev/e9a5a8a5ff803092c76a26d6721bfaf4

Answer (score 4):

I found that very simple by removing the first item and "join" the rest of the List

```
String date = "date:'2019:04:01'";
List<String> dateParts = date.split(":");
List<String> wantedParts = [dateParts.removeAt(0),dateParts.join(":")];
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use RegExp**

```
string.split(RegExp(r":\s*(?=')"));
```

1. Note the use of a raw string (a string prefixed with r)
2. `\s*` matches zero or more whitespace character
3. `(?=')` matches `'` without including itself

Answer (score 2):

You can use extensions and use this one for separating text for the RichText/TextSpan use cases:

```
extension StringExtension on String {
 List<String> controlledSplit(
  String separator, {
  int max = 1,
  bool includeSeparator = false,
  }) {
   String string = this;
   List<String> result = [];

   if (separator.isEmpty) {
     result.add(string);
     return result;
   }

   while (true) {
     var index = string.indexOf(separator, 0);
     print(index);
     if (index == -1 || (max > 0 && result.length >= max)) {
       result.add(string);
       break;
     }

     result.add(string.substring(0, index));
     if (includeSeparator) {
       result.add(separator);
     }
     string = string.substring(index + separator.length);
   }

   return result;
 }
}
```

Then you can just reference this as a method for any string through that extension:

```
void main() {
 String mainString = 'Here was john and john was here';
 print(mainString.controlledSplit('john', max:1, includeSeparator:true));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert list to string and search

```
  productModel.tagsList.toString().contains(filterText.toLowerCase())
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write an extension on Strings

```
extension StringExtension on String {
(String, String) splitFirst({String separator = ":"}) {
 int separatorPosition = indexOf(separator);
 if (separatorPosition == -1) {
  return (this, "");
 }
 return (substring(0, separatorPosition), substring(separatorPosition + separator.length));
}}
```

And use it like this

```
final (firstPart, secondPart) = yourString.splitFirst();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
   var str = 'date: 2019:04:01';
   print(str.split(" ").last.trim()); //2019:04:01
}
```