# How to compare two app versions in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to compare the two app versions in Flutter:

```
final v1 = "1.0.0";
final v2 = "1.0.1";
```

How do I state which version is bigger than the other?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Compare them as integers!

A cool solution is to convert each version to an exponential integer so that we can compare them simply as integers!

```
void main() {
  String v1 = '1.2.3', v2 = '1.2.11';
  int v1Number = getExtendedVersionNumber(v1); // return 102003
  int v2Number = getExtendedVersionNumber(v2); // return 102011
  print(v1Number >= v2Number);
}

int getExtendedVersionNumber(String version) {
  List versionCells = version.split('.');
  versionCells = versionCells.map((i) => int.parse(i)).toList();
  return versionCells[0] * 100000 + versionCells[1] * 1000 + versionCells[2];
}
```

Checkout this **[running example](https://dartpad.dev/?id=2656fd69d825844d9415fc08810554d4)** on Dartpad.

Comment: This assumes that the most minor version number never exceeds 1000 (i.e. the maximum allowed minor is 999 before the code breaks).

Comment: That's correct. Of course, it is just a use case, you can change to multiplier numbers by more than 100000 to support large version numbers.

Answer (score 12):

Since the version and revision numbers can go more than 9. We often have version numbers like "1.13.11", "211.74.23" etc. . A solution is to split and compare the individual numbers.

```
 String a = "1.39.2";
 String b = "1.38.14"; 
 bool isVersionGreaterThan(String newVersion, String currentVersion){
   List<String> currentV = currentVersion.split(".");
   List<String> newV = newVersion.split(".");
   bool a = false;
   for (var i = 0 ; i <= 2; i++){
     a = int.parse(newV[i]) > int.parse(currentV[i]);
     if(int.parse(newV[i]) != int.parse(currentV[i])) break;
   }
   return a;
 }
  print(isVersionGreaterThan(a,b));
```

Comment: Best answer here... Though I'd caution to include a check to make sure both String versions split into the same number of parts.

Answer (score 10):

Use [version](https://pub.dev/packages/version) package from pub.dev

a bit about this package

`A dart library providing a Version object for comparing and incrementing version numbers in compliance with the Semantic Versioning spec at [http://semver.org/][2]`

you can use this code to compare and perform your task

```
Version latestVersion = Version.parse("1.5.1");

if (latestVersion > Version.parse(1.3.0))
    _newUpdateDialog(); // your function here
```

Answer (score 2):

Another easy approach would be to simply use the [Version](https://pub.dev/packages/version) plugin which helps compare versions. It also handles many edge cases.

Use it like this:-

```
import 'package:version/version.dart';

void main() {

  Version currentVersion = Version.parse("10.1.0");
  // Could use like this also
  // Version currentVersion = Version(10, 1, 0);
  Version latestVersion = Version.parse("9.10.0");

  // Note: this test will print "Current version higher than latest version",
  // as the provided latest version is smaller than the current version.
  if (latestVersion > currentVersion) {
    debugPrint("Current version smaller than latest version");
    // Should update app to latest version.
  } else if (latestVersion == currentVersion) {
    debugPrint("Current version same as latest version");
    // App already using latest version.
  } else {
    debugPrint("Current version higher than latest version");
    // App using newer version than provided latest version.
  }

  //For pre-release version comparing
  Version betaVersion = Version(9, 10, 0, preRelease: ["beta"]);
  // Note: this test will return false, as pre-release versions are considered
  // lesser then a non-pre-release version that otherwise has the same numbers.
  if (betaVersion > latestVersion) {
    print("More recent beta available");
  }
}
```

**Update:-**

Just letting others know that I'm using this approach in my production app for quite a long time. And I have pushed many updates through the GitHub releases where my app uses this package to compare the current and new versions over GitHub releases. And TBH I never faced any issues. Really great package.

Answer (score 1):

according to this package on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus): `package_info_plus`

```
import 'package:package_info_plus/package_info_plus.dart';

PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();

String version = packageInfo.version;
```

the version is in String format, so you can split this string by '.' and get individual int and compare them individually, heres [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60402195/flutter-dart-split-string-by-first-occurrence) if you need

Answer (score 1):

@Asquere answer is right.
However if you want it to work with both x.x.x.x... number and when comparing

```
Future<bool> _isHigherThanCurrentVersion(String newVersion, String currentVersion) async {
  var isHigher = false;

  try {
    final currentVSegments = currentVersion.split('.');
    final newVSegments = newVersion.split('.');
    final maxLength = max(currentVSegments.length, newVSegments.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
      final newVSegment =
          i < newVSegments.length ? int.parse(newVSegments[i]) : 0;
      final currentVSegment =
          i < currentVSegments.length ? int.parse(currentVSegments[i]) : 0;
      isHigher = newVSegment > currentVSegment;
      if (newVSegment != currentVSegment) {
        break;
      }
    }
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    // this should silently fail
    // we will return false in case of parsing error
  }
  return isHigher;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All these answers doesn't work for me, so I created my own solution, because I'm work with this differents "versions" values types: **'11'**, **'11.1'**, **'11.0.0.0.0.1'**, etc....

The solution is:

```
void main() {
  String firstVersion = '11.0.1', secondVersion = '11.1';

  final List<String> first = firstVersion.split('.');
  final List<String> second = secondVersion.split('.');
  bool isHigher = false;
  
   // Here im equaliting the length of the versions
  if (first.length > second.length) {
    final size = first.length - second.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      second.add('0');
    }
  } else {
    final size = second.length - first.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      first.add('0');
    }
  }

  // Here im comparing the versions
  for (var i = 0; i < (first.length); i++) {
    isHigher =
        int.parse(first[i]) >= int.parse(second[i]);
    if (int.parse(first[i]) != int.parse(second[i])){
      break;
    }
  }

  print("Versions:");
  print('a = $firstVersion \nb = $secondVersion');
  print('\nIs a higher than b?');
  print(isHigher);
}
```

Check the code here: https://dartpad.dev/?id=2656fd69d825844d9415fc08810554d4

Answer (score 0):

```
/// Compares two versions. 
/// 
/// If the app version is `1.0.0`, and the version in the market is `1.1`,
/// then `true` will be returned.
/// 
/// If it was not possible to parse the versions, then returns `folse`.
bool isUpdateAvailable(String appVersion, String marketVersion) {
  if (appVersion.isEmpty || marketVersion.isEmpty) {
    return false;
  }

  List<int> appVersionParts = [];
  List<int> marketVersionParts = [];

  try {
    appVersionParts = _parseVersion(appVersion);
    marketVersionParts = _parseVersion(marketVersion);
  } on Exception {
    return false;
  }

  if (appVersionParts.length > marketVersionParts.length) {
    marketVersionParts = _fillVersion(marketVersionParts, appVersionParts.length);
  } else if (appVersionParts.length < marketVersionParts.length) {
    appVersionParts = _fillVersion(appVersionParts, marketVersionParts.length);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < appVersionParts.length; i++) {
    if (appVersionParts[i] < marketVersionParts[i]) {
      return true;
    }

    if (appVersionParts[i] > marketVersionParts[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

/// Parse version from String `"1.0.1"` to List [1, 0, 1].
List<int> _parseVersion(String version) {
  return version.split('.').map(int.parse).toList();
}

/// Fill the version with extra zeros. For example, from `1` to `1.0.0`.
List<int> _fillVersion(List<int> version, int neededLength) {
  for (var i = 0; i < neededLength - version.length + 1; i++) {
    version.add(0);
  }
  return version;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can convert the app version into int

```
int.parse("243.00.452".replaceAll(".",""))
```

Answer (score -1):

## Simple and easy solution

---

This an extension method on the String class. Extension methods allow you to add new methods to existing classes. In this case, the extension method `removeDotAndToInt()` is added to the String class. This method takes a string as input and returns an integer. The integer is the value of the string without the dots.

The code `"1.3.0".removeDotAndToInt() > "1.2.0".removeDotAndToInt()` compares the values of the strings `"1.3.0"` and `"1.2.0"` after the dots have been removed. The result of the comparison is `true`, which means that the value of `"1.3.0"` is greater than the value of `"1.2.0"`.

```dart
extension StringExtension on String {
  int removeDotAndToInt() => replaceAll('.', '').toInt();
}

"1.3.0".removeDotAndToInt() > "1.2.0".removeDotAndToInt();

// true
```

Comment: This isn't always correct. Consider comparing versions 1.3.1 and 1.2.14. This answer will result in the lower version of 1.2.14 calculated as the higher version.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, I got temporary solution,

```
void main() {
  String a = "1.0.0";
  String b = "1.0.1";

  int intA = int.parse(a.replaceAll(".",""));
  int intB = int.parse(b.replaceAll(".",""));

  if(intB > intA){
    print("New update available");
  }  
}
```

Comment: this solution dosn`t work. if a = 1.1.11  and b = 1.2.1 it shows that a > b and its wrong

Comment: Try this one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69821041/16907666