# Flutter - How to split string by space in the stateful widget?

Tags: string, flutter, dart, split

I'm still new to coding and I don't know how to split string in the stateful widget.

---

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for questions about the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter/Dart: Split string by first occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60402195/flutter-dart-split-string-by-first-occurrence)

Answer (score 1):

to split `String str = "Hello World!";`

you can simply use `split` method like `str.split(' ')`

Refer [this](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/dart-core/String/split.html) official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use String's `.split()` method to achieve this, passing in a string containing just a space as your delimiter. For example:

`'Hello World'.split(' ')` will return `['Hello', 'World']`.